# Using java.lang.String.format() to pad a string with given character

Tags: java, string, string.format

I have a string and I want to pad this string by any given character to a given length.
off course I can write a loop statement and get the job done but thats not what I am looking for.

One approach I used was

```
myString = String.format("%1$"+ n + "s", myString).replace(' ', newChar);
```

this works fine except when `myString` already has a space in it. Is there a better solution using String.format()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *Commons StringUtils* [rightPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) or [leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29) method, like below.

```
StringUtils.leftPad("test", 8, 'z');
```

Outputs,

> zzzztest

Answer (score 0):

If your string does not contain '0' symbols, you could do :

```
 int n = 30; // assert that n > test.length()
 char newChar = 'Z';
 String test = "string with no zeroes";
 String result = String.format("%0" + (n - test.length()) + "d%s", 0, test)
     .replace('0', newChar); 
 // ZZZZZZZZZstring with no zeroes
```

or if it does :

```
 test = "string with 0 00";
 result = String.format("%0" + (n - test.length()) + "d", 0).replace('0', newChar)
     + test;
 // ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZstring with 0 00

 // or equivalently:
 result = String.format("%" + (n - test.length()) + "s", ' ').replace(' ', newChar) 
     + test;
```